# Must restart Kernal each time when running Vpython

Tags: python-3.x, vpython

Each time I run Vpython on Jupyter Notebooks it requires that I restart the kernal for it to update/add things to the canvas. Example:I will draw an arrow, want to test it in different locations then it will immediately get rid of my original arrow and not have anything drawn.

I was wondering if this could be avoided. I would like to play around with this module more however if I need to constantly restart the kernal each time it would be cumbersome. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just add the line

```
scene = canvas()
```

For example, try this in a cell.

```
from vpython import *
scene = canvas()
box()
```

Then execute the cell. Then execute the cell again. You should see the box every time you execute the cell.